# redis multiple search with wildcards based on lat and long location near by

Tags: c#, api, redis, stackexchange.redis, node-redis

I am looking for solution, In application using middle ware as redis for DB calls reduce.

**Total record count : 1000000**

**Customer Table:**
CustomerId: 1,
CustomerFirstName: 'First Name',
lastname: 'Last name',
middlename: 'middle name',
address: 'complete full address',
zipcode: '5600036',
lat: 23.568998,
lng: 87.36966,
isactive: 1

**Query is**

**lat : 23.56899
lng : 87.25665 near by records and some filters.**

**Example Query :**
SELECT firstname, lastname, middlename, (some condition) as DISTANCE FROM Customer
WHERE firstname like '%first%' and lastname like '%last%' and zipcode ='560036'
and isactive in (1,0)
order by DISTANCE >= 25 KM**

above query is in SQL.
**now, same query required in redis.**

Could you help me out to resolve this issue. Looking for your reply

Thank you.

Comment: Redis is a key-value store. "Querying" isn't what it does.

Comment: Did you check the RediSearch module for Redis?

Comment: @GuyKorland let me check. thank you.